Absolutely continuous random variables and conditioning
Suppose I have three random variables defined on a common probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$. $X, Y$ taking values in $(\mathbb X, \mathcal X)$ and $Z$ taking values in $\mathbb Z, \mathcal Z)$.
Suppose now

$Y \ll X$ with (Radon-Nikodym) derivative $f_Y$, i.e. $E[g(Y)] = E[g(X) f_Y(X)]$ for any measurable $g$.

X has distribution function $P_X$ that admits the following disintegration $\int_A P_X(dx) = \int_{A \times \mathbb Z} P_{X | Z}(d x | z) P_Z(d z)$ where $P_{X|Z}$ is a probability kernel (regular conditional probability) and $P_Z$ is the law of $Z$.


Then, can we claim:
$i$) $(Y | Z=z) \ll (X |Z=z)$ $P_Z$-a.e?
This should be the case since
$$
\int_{\mathbb X} g(y) P_Y(d y) = \int_{\mathbb X} g(y) f_Y(y) P_X(d y) = \int_{\mathbb X \times \mathbb Z} g(y) f_Y(y) P_{X | Z} (d y | z) P_Z(d z).
$$
$ii$) if the point above is true, what is the density of $(Y | Z=z)$ given $(X |Z=z)$? I would say it is
$$
f_{Y|Z=z} (y) = \frac{f(y)}{E[f(X) | Z = z]}
$$
to ensure that $f_{Y|Z}$ integrates to 1 w.r.t $P_{X | Z}(\cdot | z)$, but I am not able to show this.

Counterexample: $X=Z$ independent of $Y$.
